# docker nothing to do, and docker commnad not found

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, kubectl, docker-machine

i followed below steps on centos 7 machine to install docker but it says nothing to do and when i run docker command it says that command not found.
i followed below steps on centos 7 machine to install docker but it says nothing to do and when i run docker command it says that command not found.

```
**sudo yum check-update
sudo yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
sudo yum install docker**
```

on some other machine same commands worked but its having some strange behaviour on this machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running following steps solved the issue:

1. some how firewall started creating problem , so i had to check
   the internet connection as below: 
   curl --location-trusted --ntlm --user "xyz" www.google.com enter password
2. yum install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.107-3.el7.noarch.rpm
3. yum -y install docker-ce